open back or closed back speaker cabinet?
I'm about to start making another cabinet, this time with a Peavey Renown amp, and two 12" speakers. The original had an open back (I used one in the '80s '90s for guitar), but over the years have used both open and closed back.
This question is a follow up from one I posed last year. Would there be any mileage in making a cab. with a hinged back, thus having the advantage of both open and closed? Easy to do in the making rather than after.
It's not a dupe, as the last question is more about ported/non-ported cabs.

It's been done before. Do what you want - it's a matter of taste.

@Todd Wilcox - Many, many things have 'been done before'. True. But I haven't done them. So, I'm asking for those experienced in having done them before to offer their tuppenceworth, and explain the taste differences.

So you already know whether there would be any mileage in it and you are aware it’s opinion based?

@ToddWilcox - not so much opinion but experience.

Re; experience, I have performed in a variety of settings and venues over the years, and I used both closed-back and open back amplifiers and speaker cabs.
It's funny that it never occurred to me before, Tim, but it really is a brilliant idea.
If it has been done before, it's odd that I never encountered one with a back door like that.
There are times when I would liked to have had the option.

Just make sure when the back is closed, it's sealed somehow as well otherwise you may get noise from the air pressure from inside pushing through the cracks

@Duston - I would carpet the rest of the cab and the panel, (exhibition carpet), and make each section a good fit. It may not be completely airtight, but as good as I can get it. Thanks. Sounds, so far, like it's not a bad idea...

In my opinion, building your speaker cabinet with hinged back would be an excellent idea.
In the end, you would end up with sonic opportunities and alternatives that would not exist for a performer with just the conventional designs on his or her stage.
Fabulous idea, really.

I wouldn’t use hinges because they are almost impossible to keep 100% free from rattling.

Sure, why not?   If the difference isn't useful, you've lost nothing.

Except it's easier to screw a plain piece of wood straight on the back! Whether half way up, or covering the lot!

Indeed.  But isn't the point here to have both options easily available?

Not my dv, but I want to make once, rather than re-make.
